# Turn a for loop into a foreach loop

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have some working code here and I am wondering if there is a way to modify the for loop into a foreach loop.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])==true){
$count = intval($_POST['clickCount']);
$count += 1;

//change this for loop into a foreach
for ($copying =0; $copying <1; $copying++){
   echo $_SESSION['question'][$count-1];
}



}else{
echo "Welcome to trivia! Enter your answer below for the following question:        
<br><br>";
echo $_SESSION['question'][0];
$count = 1;


}
```

Comment: That loop you have will only loop once though (`$copying =0; $copying <1`). But yeah, you can do `foreach ($_SESSION['question'] as $key=>$value)`

Comment: See [PHP.net on control structure: foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @Qirel it is only suppose to loop through once, i am reading a line from a txt file and I only want one line to be echoed

Comment: What's the point of a loop, if it has only one iteration? :p